# Working with classes [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, class, constructor, accessor, mutators

I tried searching for answers for this error and tried the suggested fixes but nothing helped so I am asking for help. I keep receiving id returned 1 exit status error. I am using Dev-C++ as the IDE.

This is my header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;

class Record
{
    private:
        string name;
        int id;
        double rate;
        double hours;
    public: 
        Record();
        Record (string n, int empid, double hourlyRate, double hoursWorked); 
 // constructor

        void read_data_from_file();
        double calculate_wage();
        void print_data();

        /* SETTERS AND GETTERS */           
        void set_name (string n);
        string get_name();

        void set_id (int empid);
        int get_id();

        void set_rate (double hourlyRate);
        double get_rate();

        void set_hoursWorked(double hoursWorked);
        double get_hoursWorked();
        /* END OF SETTERS AND GETTERS */            
};
```

and this is my Record.cpp

```
#include "Record.h"

Record::Record(string n, int empid, double hourlyRate, double hoursWorked)
{
    name = n;
    empid = id;
    hourlyRate = rate;
    hoursWorked = hours;
}
//
void Record::set_name(string n)
{
     name = n;
}
 string Record::get_name()
{
     return name;
}
 //
 void Record::set_id(int empid)
 {
     id = empid;
 }
 int Record::get_id()
 {
     return id;
 }
//
 void Record::set_rate(double hourlyRate)
 {
    rate = hourlyRate;
 }
 double Record::get_rate()
 {
     return rate;
 }
 //
 void Record::set_hoursWorked(double hoursWorked)
 {
     hours = hoursWorked;
 }
 double Record::get_hoursWorked()
 {
     return hours;
 }
 //
```

And ofcourse, I have an int main() function.

```
#include "Record.h" 
int main() 
{   
    Record employee; 
    ifstream myFile; 
    return 0; 
}
```

Just a side note: this is my first project related to using class, there might be an easier way to do this, but this is what I could think of.

Comment: Can we see your main function?

Comment: What was the full error?

Comment: I will edit the post with the main

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to implement the default constructor (which you call in main). Add this to your .cpp:

```
Record::Record() : name(), id(0), rate(0), hours(0) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dev C++ IDE allows you to call a default constructor without implementation. The problem was happening due to calling because you are not calling the default or other constructor. Implementation is another thing. In main you have need just

```
Record employee();
Record employee1("temp",1,12.2,43.4);
```